# Get "requests.exceptions.SSLError" in sending requests to the dropbox api using flask application

Tags: python, ssl, flask, request, dropbox

I am trying to make requests to the dropbox api in my flask application. I am getting this error:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError

The detail of error is as below:

> Detailed Error message -
> requests.exceptions.SSLError: >HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.dropboxapi.com', port=443): Max retries >exceeded with url: /2/files/list_folder (Caused by >SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] >certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate >(_ssl.c:1129)')))

I understood SSl certificate is missing but how to establish one.
P.S. I am not using the requests python package

```
client = dropbox.Dropbox(dropbox_access_token)
print("[SUCCESS] dropbox account linked")
```

Error while executing this statement:

```
client.files_upload(open(computer_path, "rb").read(), dropbox_path)<-----
print("[UPLOADED] {}".format(computer_path))
```

Comment: What version of the `dropbox` library did you install, and how did you install it? It should handle the SSL/TLS connection for you, using the included [trusted-certs.crt](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/main/dropbox/trusted-certs.crt).

Comment: I am using dropbox 11.13.3

Comment: I am calling fb API as well and the same issue is encountered.